# unitary matrix complexity multiplication

Tags: signal-analysis, matrix, linear-algebra

Having a unitary matrix $X$ whose size is $n \times n$ and a vector $z$ whose length is $n$, and let's have:

$$y = X^H {\rm diag}(z)X$$

where $X^H$ is the conjugate transpose of $X$.

My question, is the complexity of this multiplication is still  almost $n^3$ or since the matrix $X$ is unitary, multiplication complexity should be less ?

Comment: What is H...another unitary matrix?

Comment: I must admit I don't see how this is signal processing?

Comment: @Dspguysam .. Sorry I modified it, it's $X$ it's not $H$.

Comment: @MarcusMüller A computation that sounds quite DSP-like, indeed not in the core business